# How to set default browser on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, firefox, default-browser

I want to set Firefox as the default browser on Ubuntu Touch so that links in Dekko, RSS reader, etc. open in Firefox instead of the Ubuntu touch browser. I can't find a "default browser" setting in the settings app. Setting Firefox to default inside Firefox does nothing.

I use some add-ons in Firefox as well as syncing tabs and bookmarks with my desktop, so I really don't want to be forced to use another browser by every link I open on Ubuntu touch.

I'm using the Bq M10 FHD with OTA 11.

Comment: I have the same issue with other paps such as Dekko. I want to set it as the default email client, not the Gmail web app. However, there is no option too. It seems lile this option has been left out of the settings section totally.

Comment: Hi! You should probably make a bug report in launchpad. I did for the default browser issue (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1607860), and the bug is confirmed, so at some point, someone might have a look at it to decide if it is worth fixing. (I just asked here because I though maybe there already was a way that I was unaware of.)

Comment: Since this is on an m10, I assume you're running Firefox in a libertine container. I don't believe it's possible to set a libertine app as a default in Ubuntu Touch using the UI currently. There might be some workaround if you're willing to make the tablet writable and muck with some system files. I agree with @radiomasten that you should mark yourself as affected on that bug.

Answer (score 0):

open the Settings utility, move to the Details tab, click on the Default Applications and then select your preferred web browser through the Web drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** Go to Settings > Default Applications > Select "Firefox Web Browser" in the drop down for "Web".
**Method 2:** In Firefox, open a new tab, click the burger menu in the top-right corner > Settings, then under "Startup" you'll see "Firefox is not your default browser". Click "Set as default", then allow it to change the default app.